# Por que esse erro no PostgreSQL se não estou usando SSL?

Tags: delphi, postgresql, zeos

Por que estou recebendo esse erro:

> SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected

A conexão é pela rede local via Aplicação Delphi -> PosgtreSQL
Faço uso do componente ZEOS para a conexão

Comment: Poste o código que origina o erro para podermos ajudar. Explique em que momento esse erro é apresentado (abertura do programa? "Open" da query?)

Comment: Rapaz eu até gostaria de colocar o código o problema é que não encontrei em que momento isso ocorre com precisão, pois a aplicação está conectada sem uso e do nada da esse erro, não sei onde debugar pra pegar esse erro

Comment: Hmm, tem algum Timer no programa, ou alguma Thread que use acesso ao banco ou acesso à web?

Comment: Exitste um timer sim que faz consulta de minuto em minuto (no minimo), já deixei com esse tempo pra não dar sobrecarga... repasseis as duas querys relacionadas a esse timer e não consegui ver nada de anormal nelas, inclusive pegando o Text no Debug e executando pelo pgAdmin, olhando na internet dei uma incrementada no componente ZConnection, a principio parece que melhorou, vou monitorar pra ver o resultado, parece que surtiu efeito, se der certo coloco a solução aqui.

Comment: Vc desativa o Timer quando começa e reativa depois que ele executa as queries? (Enable False/True)
Eu imaginei que uma query esteja executando "em cima" da outra, antes da anterior concluir. Acha que pode ser o caso?

Comment: Não tem nenhuma query que dure mais de um minuto, acho que resolvi o problema, coloquei algumas opções no componente, codepage=UTF8
AutoEncodeStrings=ON
controls_cp=GET_ACP
isc_tpb_read_commited
isc_tpb_concurrency
isc_tpb_nowait
exit_on_error=off
Ja fa um bom tempo que nao da o erro, pelo que vi sem essas opções existia acesso exclusivo em algumas tabelas gerando crash pra algumas maquinas, espero ter resolvido... isso tirou minhas noites de sono.